# How to remove field and fit that section after remove field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I created invoice bill using crystal report. Its looks something like this.

I need something like this. My client want to add Description below this amount. Description mean number. its coming from database like other fields. But that description is not every time print. Its mean sometimes that field is blank. I want to if that field is empty hide it and fit that section. I don't want to keep blank field every time. I want to if description is have I want to show is. if description is not i want to print only recordNo, item name, descountprice, quantity and amount without space.

```
Name | Price  |  Qty | Amount 
-----------------------------
1 Phone    1500 X   2     3000
This is description 
2 Mouse    1000 X   5     5000
No description. Blank field. I want to remove this
3 Fan      400  X   2     800
```

if no have any description I want to remove field and remove gap between 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place that field in its own section and, in Section Expert for that section, use the option to 'Suppress Blank Section' or use a dynamic expression for the Suppress property:
[image]